What does the Program counter have as next instruction when a program ends?
What's the state of the program counter once the last instruction is being executed in a program as there's no next instruction to be fetched?

When you say "last instruction", do you mean a HALT instruction (which literally stops the computer) or something else?

I'm not 100% sure but I think you're comparing apples to oranges. The host operating system's scheduler decides which processes and threads are allocated time on the processor and sets/resets the processor's registers when swapping between them. Your program sits in an abstraction above the scheduler, once it's time has come then any resources associated with the running program are released back to the OS.

The program counter register (PC) otherwise known as the instruction pointer (IP) always points at the next instruction to be executed.  When an instruction is fetched, the PC is set to point to the next instruction, and it keeps pointing at the next instruction while the instruction that was previously fetched is being executed.
There is no such thing as "no more next instructions to be fetched".
Just because your program has no more instructions to execute, it does not mean that the CPU has nothing else to do.  Depending on the operating system, your program may end with a RET instruction which returns to the operating system, or it may end with some other instruction that in some other way returns control back to the operating system. Rest assured that the fact that your little program has ended is of very little importance to the operating system; the operating system always has more stuff to do.
If the operating system decides to put the CPU in some low-power state, there are various ways in which this may be achieved, but the general concept is that the CPU clock is frozen for a certain period of time.  When the CPU clock resumes, execution continues exactly there where the PC left off, as if the clock was never frozen.

Can any real system ret directly back to the OS?  On x86 it would have to be a far retf unless you had a cooperative multi-tasking system that runs everything sharing the same CS.  More normally it's an int or syscall, like in a DOS .com program where a ret pops a return address that points IP at an int 0x20 instruction, IIRC, which is a DOS exit system call.  The ret itself just jumps within the program.

@PeterCordes I vaguely seemed to remember that .com programs end with a ret, I did not know it points to int 0x20, but that's a technical detail. Anyway, I just thought that there could conceivably be some tiny system out there that just returns to the OS.  Who knows, maybe CP/M or something.

Maybe on a machine where addresses are really only 16 bits wide so there's at most 64K?  On x86 a near ret could only jump within the same CS so that's implausible, but not weird at all on a machine where all of memory is a flat 16-bit address-space like 8080 or 6502.  Anyway, I think syscall would be a better example for an answer in 2024; most people are used to multitasking OSes with different privilege levels for kernel vs. user-space but ret doesn't change privs.  x86-64 and a few other ISAs have an instruction literally called syscall whose name is pretty self-explanatory.

@PeterCordes yes, of course, that's why I wrote "or it may end with some other instruction that in some other way returns control back to the operating system".  I just did not want to become too technical.

@PeterCordes DOS flat-format (.COM) executables indeed start with a zero word on their stack (often at ss:0FFFEh but not always), and ss = cs = PSP, so that running a retn with the initial stack jumps to PSP:0. To allow terminating a program like this, every PSP starts with a 2-byte int 20h instruction. On some versions of DOS the interrupt 20h service requires its calling cs to point at a PSP, on others any int 20h call will terminate the current process regardless where that is located.

During execution of the int or syscall that makes an _exit system call, or a faulting load or store that results in the program crashing as a way to end, the "next instruction" referenced by the program counter is the one in memory directly after the current instruction, as always.
Since the instruction actually traps to the OS which chooses not to return to user-space, instead to tear down the process, that's not the next instruction that actually executes.
But you asked about PC during execution of an instruction.  For ISAs that support PC-relative addressing, this actually matters.  (Jumps and faulting instructions don't update PC until after a PC-relative addressing mode is resolved, so the target address is only dependent on the location of the instruction, not other data.)
For example, an x86-64 program could end with mov eax, [rip + 0xbadbeef], which will cause a #PF (page-fault) exception, assuming the page(s) containing the 32-bit dword are unmapped.  (On Linux for example, the OS will deliver SIGSEGV to your process, or just kill it if you haven't installed a signal handler for that signal.)
The anchor point for x86-64 RIP-relative addressing is the end of the current instruction, i.e. mov al, [rip + 0] loads the byte following the current instruction.
So we can say that x86-64's RIP (the 64-bit Instruction Pointer aka Program Counter) during execution of any instruction is the same as always, pointing at the byte after the end of this instruction.
(Some other ISAs have a different anchor point for PC-relative addressing, e.g. on RISC-V it's the start of the current instruction; on ARM it's 2 instructions onward due to historical pipelined implementations exposing that implementation detail.)

After execution of an int / syscall / ecall or whatever other instruction transferred control back to the OS, the program counter will be pointing at the OS's entry point for that method of transferring control to it.  (e.g. for a user-space syscall in x86-64 Linux, at the entry_SYSCALL_64 block whose code is hand-written in asm in arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S in the kernel source.)
Only in toy ISAs like LC-3 used for teaching will your program end with a HALT or something that literally means there is no next instruction since the simulator stops simulating.  That's like powering off the machine so after it completes, PC has no value.
(On real ISAs like x86, an instruction like hlt actually just puts the CPU into a lowish-power sleep until the next hardware interrupt, e.g. from the keyboard controller or timer interrupt.  An OS might use that in its idle loop if there were no tasks waiting for CPU time.)
